# Create for loop with changing image

Tags: javascript, html, function, loops, for-loop

I haven't been able to find my specific case on here yet so I thought I'd ask. I'm trying to make a very simple Tamagotchi in Javascript for a school project. Musts are that I apply DOM manipulation, use a loop, use an array(or an object), and use a function.

My idea was to make an array with all the 'emotions' as images and then a `for` loop to slowly count them down. Giving the impression that the mood of the Tamagotchi gets worse as time passes.

This is the code I have so far, it's not a lot:

```
var imgArray = ["super.png", "blij.png", "neutraal.png", "meh.png", "verdrietig.png", "dood.png"] //Array with the images

for (var i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++)
{
    //for loop that counts down array
    //Here I want a function that changes the image according to the array number
}
```

Sorry for the bad formatting, this is my first time on here :)

This is what I have in the body:

```
<h1>Tamagotchi</h1>

<button id="feed">Give food</button>

<button id="play">Entertain</button>

<button id="walk">Walk</button>

<div id="tamagotchi"></div>
```

I'd also then like the buttons that you see above to add points to make the Tamagotchi feel better (so in the for loop the array automatically keeps `++i` but I'd like the button to `--i`, so subtract one point) `imgArray[0]` is the happiest and `imageArray[5]` is the saddest.

I hope this wasn't too vague, please let me know if I need to better explain anything!

Comment: Ok, so you've told us what you'd like, but what have you tried so far and what ***specific*** single question do you have?

Comment: 1. How do I change the image in the div using a for loop and my array
2. How do I make it so my buttons make the array go up 1. I'm very obviously a beginner and I just don't know how to start and where to look.

Comment: That's not really a single question about a specific issue. That's asking for the solution to a process and that isn't what we do here. First, you may want to explain (for those who don't know) what a Tamagotchi is. Next, you don't have any image in the div, so we can't really tell you how to change it. Second, if this is an assignment and you've been instructed to use the DOM, what have you learned so far as to working with the DOM? Please read [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get a better feel for what the expectations are of you when you ask a question.

Comment: So here are some guidelines of what you should study (from my deleted answer):  https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp to learn about events (and how can change variables with a press of a button).
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp - to handle a countdown timer.
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp - to handle variables in multiple functions/scopes.

Comment: Personally, I would advise that you stay as far away from W3Schools as you can. It's well known that W3Schools provides incomplete, out of date, or flat out wrong information. But, because they do a great job with their search engine optimization, they come up at the top of most programming searches and this causes legions of new developers to learn bad techniques or out dated approaches. I would recommend the [Mozilla Developers Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn), which is highly regarded as an authoritative source on most web-related programming issues.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some draft so you can start from something. I've created a function allowing you to improve the state of the tamagoshi.

**For you now :**

- Making a function to decrease it
- Make them to be displayed as image and not strings
- Make it prettier using css rules

If you get trouble with the code, Stack Overflow will help. SO is not made to write code from scratch, but to fix bug and coding issues.

```js
// Array with the images
const imgArray = [
  'super.png',
  'blij.png',
  'neutraal.png',
  'meh.png',
  'verdrietig.png',
  'dood.png',
];

let tamagoshiState;

// Pointer to the div where you are going to insert the picture
const tamagoshiFeel = document.getElementById('tamagotchi');

// Function that can change the state of the tamagoshi
function setTamagoshiState(i) {
   tamagoshiState = i;
   tamagoshiFeel.innerHTML = imgArray[i];
}

// Change the tamagoshi state in a positive way
function improveTamagoshiState() {
  // Tamagoshi can't be happier
  if (tamagoshiState === 0) {
    return;
  }

  setTamagoshiState(tamagoshiState - 1);
}

// Initialize the tamagoshi state at very sad
setTamagoshiState(imgArray.length - 1);
```

```css
#tamagotchi {
  margin-top: 2em;
}
```

```html
<h1>Tamagotchi</h1>

<button id="feed" onclick="improveTamagoshiState()">Give food</button>

<button id="play" onclick="improveTamagoshiState()">Entertain</button>

<button id="walk" onclick="improveTamagoshiState()">Walk</button>

<!-- How the tamagochi feels -->
<div id="tamagotchi">

</div>
```

Comment: Please don't post answers to questions that shouldn't be here in the first place as it just rewards and encourages more poor questions.

Comment: It is however very tempting not to when one sees an interesting challenge ;)

Comment: @mplungjan That's true and I'm guilty of it myself from time to time.

Comment: @mplungjan between compilation time, it gives something to do ^^. It's also not the worst question I saw in here, It's described, with code and asked nicely.

Comment: But it doesn't meet our threshold for questions as you, yourself point out in your answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for your effort Gregory! I'll take a look at it. And sorry scott marcus, I should have read the guidelines